# sql-dump piping output to the screen

Tags: drush

I am trying to dump a remote Drupal site to a local SQL dump file. In Drush 8 this worked a treat:

```
drush @site.alias sql-dump > ~/Dumps/dumpy.2019-02-19.sql
```

Now, if I run this command in Drush 9 (9.4.0) I see the raw SQL just printed on the screen.

If I add `2>&1` to the command, this does not help.

If I add a `--result-file=` this creates a file on the remote server (not what I want).

Does anyone have any ideas here?

Comment: Please try with the latest stable Drush, 9.5.2, or better yet, try out the 9.6.0-beta3 release. If you have problems, please submit a bug report to the Drush issue queue.

Comment: Yep. I was able to dump the database locally with `Drush version : 9.5.2`

Comment: heh, the Drush Github issue queue said to raise questions here. Will see if I can update Drush.

Comment: I experience this problem with `dr --version` saying 9.7.1. On the remote server, it is the same version. I verified this with `dr @remotealias version`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output on the screen is caused by a bug in Drush.

From https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/4004#issuecomment-479155241:

> The problem is that Drush is setting tty mode even though output is redirected. This is wrong.

**Workaround 1** via the command line:

```
drush -Dssh.tty=0 @site.alias sql-dump > ~/Dumps/dumpy.2019-02-19.sql
```

**Workaround 2** via the YAML file that defines the remote, as suggested at https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/4004#issuecomment-500157166:

> For anyone coming across this issue. I had a similar problem with Drush 9.7.0 where sql:dump output was sent to standard output instead of a file. Based on the above workaround, I fixed it with the 'ssh' option in the drush alias of the remote site:

```
site.alias:
  ssh:
    tty: 0
```

Comment: Awesome.. Tried workaround1. and it worked for me. thanks !!

Comment: Using drush 10.3.5 also printed output to the screen. Used Workaround 1 to save it in the file.

Comment: One caveat to workaround 2 is that `drush @site.alias sql:cli` will stop working we've discovered